# Unable to click in image and video editing sofware after lost focus

Tags: windows-10, gimp

As the title says, when I'm using a image or video editing software like Premiere, Illustrator or GIMP and have it continue to run in the background when playing games the software crashes in a strange way.

I'm unable to click in the program. The clicks just go straight through. The keyboard command still works though.

The problem first occurred in Premiere so I thought it was a Adobe related error but now lately I have gotten it in GIMP also.